# integrating bootstrap classes to have a dropdown list using the Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

trying to make a drop once click on the html action, works with anchor tag
As per below it works with

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#auth" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="auth">
              <p>Testing<span class="dropdown-toggle"></span> </p>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="auth">
              <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="pages/samples/login.html"> Home 1 </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="pages/samples/login-2.html"> Home 2 </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="pages/samples/register.html"> Home 3 </a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
```

[working with  tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4QHi.png)

as per below does not work.\

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" id="User">
              <i class="fas fa-user-edit " style="margin-left: 30px;margin-top: 6px;">  </i>
              @Html.ActionLink("User Management", "Index", "Users", null, new { @class = "nav-link dropdown-toggle", data_toggle = "dropdown", aria_expanded = "false" })
              <div class="collapse">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                  <li>
                      <a class="nav-link">Home 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a class="nav-link">Home 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a class="nav-link">Home 3</a>
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </div>
          </li>
```

Comment: "Does not work" isn't a very helpful explanation. Please show us the generated source so we can compare it with what you want. Actually, studying the generated source would probably help you solve this yourself.